# Javascript button appear animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the back to top button that appears when you reach a point on the page, which is working fine, however, when it appears the text is on two lines until the box has finished the animation to appear. So, is there anyway to prevent this? What I mean by the animation is: `btt.show('slow');`

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var btt = $('.back-to-top');

    btt.on('click' , function(e) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 500);
        btt.hide('slow');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var self = $(this),
            height = self.height(),
            top = self.scrollTop();
        if (top > 500) {
            btt.show('slow');
        } else {
            btt.hide('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Example: http://codepen.io/Riggster/pen/WvNvQm

Comment: It is very difficult to tell what is going on if you do not provide more context in terms of code. Ideally you should provide relevant HTML/CSS along with your JS so that we can see what the issue is. Even better would be a working jsfiddle demonstrating your issue.

Comment: Could you post a sample of what it looks like in a page? A jsfiddle would probably go a long way.

Comment: jsfiddle please so we know what you're trying to do and we can help you.

Comment: @TimMcClureI have added a codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by animating the `width` of a box, I think it might be better to animate the `position` of it instead, but - even better - lets use CSS animations!

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 500) {
        $(".button").addClass('show');
    } else {
        $(".button").removeClass('show');
    }
});
```

```css
#wrapper { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 2000px;
}
.button {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: -100px;
    /* You might still need prefixes here. Use as preferred. */
    transition: right 500ms;
}
.button.show {
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="button">Here's my button!</div>
</div>
```

I've defined your button as hidden by default, by giving it a `position` of `right: -100px`. When we hit the correct scroll position, we add the class `show` and that triggers the animation performed by CSS and not javascript, as we have the `transition` property for the property `right` defined - that way the browser does the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 0):

Toggling show/hide alters your elements width. You either have to put it in a container with `display: inline`

Or more ideally you might want to change show/hide to jQuery fadeIn() / fadeOut() which is more appropriate for "Back to Top" indicators.

Here is your codepen example modified with inline container:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwWweY